# Sorting data in a function using a named column that has had a suffix added to it using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that takes a dataframe and a column

I want to sort by the column name

Along the dataflow, a suffix is added to all the fields within the dataframe

how can I use the arrange function and also take account for the suffix?

```
library(tidyverse)

fn<-function(df, col){
df%>%
rename_with(~ paste0(.,".suffix"))%>%
arrange(paste0(col,".suffix"))}

fn(df=iris, col="Sepal.Width")
```

Can anyone amend the above code so that it will sort by the Sepal.Width.suffix column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `.data` pronoun in `arrange`:

Note: For more on the `.data` pronoun see e.g. [Subsetting the .data pronoun](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html#subsetting-the-data-pronoun).

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

fn <- function(df, col) {
  df %>%
    rename_with(~ paste0(., ".suffix")) %>%
    arrange(.data[[paste0(col, ".suffix")]])
}

df_sorted <- fn(df = iris, col = "Sepal.Width")

head(df_sorted)
#>   Sepal.Length.suffix Sepal.Width.suffix Petal.Length.suffix Petal.Width.suffix
#> 1                 5.0                2.0                 3.5                1.0
#> 2                 6.0                2.2                 4.0                1.0
#> 3                 6.2                2.2                 4.5                1.5
#> 4                 6.0                2.2                 5.0                1.5
#> 5                 4.5                2.3                 1.3                0.3
#> 6                 5.5                2.3                 4.0                1.3
#>   Species.suffix
#> 1     versicolor
#> 2     versicolor
#> 3     versicolor
#> 4      virginica
#> 5         setosa
#> 6     versicolor
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on a need to 'audit' one's data as it churns through the workflow, one might, using `base`, reorder columns and sort, while preserving the 'where did it came from' row numbers:

```
iris2 = iris[, c(2,1,3,4,5)] # agnostic to 'suffix'
head(iris2[ do.call(order, iris2), ], n = 6)
    Sepal.Width Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
61          2.0          5.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
63          2.2          6.0          4.0         1.0 versicolor
120         2.2          6.0          5.0         1.5  virginica
69          2.2          6.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
42          2.3          4.5          1.3         0.3     setosa
94          2.3          5.0          3.3         1.0 versicolor
```

And change column order again if desirable.